# Is there a shorter way to calculate if (a == b || a == c) in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am wondering if in c++11 you can calculate this:

```cpp
if (a == b || a == c) {
    // do something
}
```

In a much shorter and more concise way such as something like this:

```cpp
if (a == (b || c)) {
    // do something
}
```

(I know that the above code would not work [it would calculate if b or c and *then* check if the result is equal to a]. I am wondering if there is a similar way to implement the code before: `if (a == b || a == c) {}`)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to rewrite this condition? Original works perfectly well. One way to rewrite is preferably a function or macro. BTW there is a short circuit while calculating the value.

Comment: Are you trying to save keystrokes, or to make the code faster?

Comment: @Sneftel I am just trying to clean up my code a little bit and make it easier to read.

Comment: With a sufficiently modern compiler, you could write `if (std::set{b, c}.contains(a))`, but I'm not sure this is an improvement.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is a good soulution for bools, but I am comparing strings, and this function seems to only allow for bools. [please correct me if I'm wrong]

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, for noticing that, I meant ||, I'll edit it now.

Comment: It would work with any type that could be put into an `std::set`, including `std::string`

Comment: I'm sort of lost here, what types are we talking about? I can see optimizations but for bools and ints for example, perhaps for strings too. But these are different paths of solution.

Comment: Yes.  Assuming `c` is appropriate type.

Comment: use ternary operator

Comment: For chars, you could do:  if (strchr(a, “bcdefg”) != NULL)

Comment: If you want to cleanup your code (and a,b,c aren't char's) then give them more readable names and put your or's in a function with a name what the logic is doing. Also note that 'or' and 'and' are smart enough to stop evaluating early : e.g. for 'or' if (a==b) is true then it doesn't evaluate (a==c) since it already knows the end result will be true. So actually your way of writing it down will be fast (a lot faster then using std::set)

Comment: You could use variadic templates for this. [Here's](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aqj6nPK4Y) an example where you call a compare function recursively, peeling of the arguments one by one and comparing it with the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are basically doing is testing if a equals a value in a set. And yes std::set can be used but its slow. This example is a bit slower then hard coding the full expression. But it shows what is being calculated and the righthand side will look like a set/collection.

```
#include <utility> // for std::size_t

template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
inline constexpr bool is_any_of(const type_t& lhs, const type_t(&set)[N])
{
    for (const auto& rhs : set)
    {
        if (lhs == rhs) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = 1;
    constexpr int b = 3;
    constexpr int c = 2;
    constexpr int d = 1;

    static_assert(!is_any_of(a, { b, c }));
    static_assert(is_any_of(a, { b, d }));
    static_assert(is_any_of(a, { b, c, d }));
    
    return 0;
}
```